# Writing a Web Scraper in Node.js - First Attempt

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to take a crack at writing my first web scraper tool in Node.js since Python always gives me trouble on my Windows 11 machine. Yet, on Kali Linux 2021.3, it works flawlessly. I even have Python in my C:\ProgramFiles\Python310\python.exe, but it seems pip is still in app data. It's frustrating.

Anyway, I am trying to use the Cheerio node.js module. Still, I wanted to make sure I was even doing this correctly. I want to try and give trends.vc a try, or maybe Google search results if that page is too limited. I used ZAP in Kali to get all the URLs on trends.vc, but I am unsure if I can use them all together in one function or not.

I am experimenting with web scrapers, seeing if I can collect a list of emails from join.trends.vc or just the Google Search result method.

Below is my code for the javascript after creating a package.json and using `npm test` as my test command, which yields nothing as I am sure I messed this up a while ago. I also tried implementing request-promise and [html-email-scraper](https://github.com/dmathijs/email-scraper), and others, but I know I am writing this wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be well appreciated.

At this point in time, I am just attempting to scrape the emails from this one page and convert it into a CSV. I followed some tutorials and managed to get those working, but not for the pages I am trying to scrape.

```js
const request = require("request-promise")
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('post.csv');

request("https://join.trends.vc/", (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const datarow = $(".form01");
    const output = datarow.find("div").text();
    $(".field").each((i, data) => {
      const item = $(data).text();
      const item1 = $(data).text();

      // Write Row To CSV
      writeStream.write(`${title}, ${link}, ${date} \n`);
    });
    // console.log(item);
    console.log(item, item1);
  }
});
```

Comment: I also tried it in Python3 as well here:
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://join.trends.vc/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("div", {"class:", "inner"})

for i in data:
    for j in i.contents[1].find_all("i"):
       print(j.get('href'))`

Comment: What output do you want, exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen just a .csv file. I think Google Search results for various trends would be better than trends.vc though since they have so many URLs I could only access through ZAP.

Comment: What goes in the CSV file?

Comment: @ggorlen For this particular one, I wanted to scrape emails. I am also following a tutorial on Google Search API, following scraperbox. I am mainly trying to get a web scraper to work and then customize it to show the top trending fields in specific tech fields like mobile and web app development.

Comment: That's all helpful background context, but what emails from the site are you specifically trying to scrape? I don't see any obvious emails after clicking on the link. It's hard to help without knowing what the output is supposed to be, exactly. I'm looking for information like "the expected output is `foo@bar.com, baz@quux.com, ...` because these are in the emails in the `.foo-bar` elements" or something like that.

Comment: The div class id for the email input would be "form01-untitled" in "<input type="email" name="untitled" id="form01-untitled" placeholder="Your Email Address..." maxlength="128" required="" data-dashlane-rid="3ec9c457e9cfc8f2" data-kwimpalastatus="alive" data-kwimpalaid="1641335353305-0" data-form-type="email">", and for the emails I am unsure. Excluding my dashlane one...

Comment: I see that form input, but I'm confused because your code and explanation looks like it's trying to extract data from the page, not input data into a form. What are you trying to input into that form? You can't use cheerio to fill out forms generally speaking -- Puppeteer would be the way to go.

Comment: Okay, thank you I will look into Puppeteer instead. And yeah, I have been rewriting it so many times trying to get it to work, it looks a lot different now. At the time I was trying to get two different items extracted, but at this point, I am just trying to get something to work and learn from that.

Comment: Currently, I am just trying to get Python and Pip working on my Windows 11 machine atm here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585775/something-is-wrong-with-my-python-on-windows